# What does 二系列の交叉点　mean?

Tags: meaning

I’m currently reading a Japanese text about political philosophy, but I can’t put my head around the term **二系列の交叉点**. It comes up in the following sentence and is frequently used afterwards.

人類と社会の未来と俺の未来、普遍への自己犠牲的献身と私的環境の中での現在のエゴイズム、この**二系列の交叉点**に立ってどちらかの択一を強制されている。

All possible translations I came up with didn't quite fit.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I think as mackygoo's translation shows, it's seems to mean the the point where two ideas cross, or conversely the point where they separate and go in different directions, in other words, a cross road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

系列A：人類と社会の未来＝普遍への自己犠牲的献身。
系列B：俺の未来＝私的環境の中での現在のエゴイズム。

二系列の交叉点とは系列Aと系列Bの交叉点。

Now you are standing at the center of the crossing of two ways: A and B. You are forced to select one of the ways of living between A and B. To live for the contribution to others or to live for your selfish way is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my interpretation.  So you have only 1 choice: the green or the red.

[image]